# How to deploy Python script that imports Tensorflow to AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, lambda

Tensorflow is a large library that is about 399 MB zipped up. I am using **tensorflow_hub** to download the pre-trained Universal Sentence Encoder model. However, **tensorflow_hub** has many dependencies on **tensorflow**.

My zipped package right now is close to 500MB. Is there any way that I can solve this issue of having to include tensorflow in my deployment? Or is there another service similar to AWS Lambda that has a larger package size limit.

Answer (score 0):

I created a script that remove from tensorflow lib the test files and **pycache**:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
pip install tensorflow --target tensorflow-layer
cd tensorflow-layer
find . -type d -name "tests" -exec rm -rfv {} +
find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -exec rm -rfv {} +
cc ..
mv tensorflow-layer python
zip -r python tensorflow-layer.zip
```

It does not remove much but can still help you to get the extra Megabytes needed for smaller libs

ps: Do not forget to have the corresponding environment (in that case python3, that would dl tensorflow 2.10) and make sure you zip your layer in a folder named according to the lambda corresponding language, but obviously you are already aware about this.